# Echo information from json php

Tags: php, json

I have a link that is as follows example.com/jsonstat

and the raw data it shows is below. How can I echo the fields where ever I want example

```
<span>threads</span>
<span>members</span>
```

etc

```
{
    "threads": 3,
    "posts": 0,
    "members": 2,
    "role_members": {
        "Guest": 0,
        "Unconfirmed": 0,
        "Moderator": 0,
        "Administrator": 0
            },
    "total_views": "16"
}
```

Comment: How does the HTML relate to the JSON?

Comment: There is not nearly enough information here to provide an informed answer. You have this question tagged as `PHP`, but there is no mention of PHP in the actual question body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're wanting is to turn JSON (text) data into an object that can be "queried" or peered into to extract the data you're wanting. In the example below, we first set up a variable "$json_data" with the text of your JSON document. The first real trick is to use json_decode to turn that into a "$data" object that has properties you can use.

All that's left to do after that is to echo these properties, which we do on the threads?> lines.. the  is just a short hand tag for "echo". Objects and properties are separated using the -> operator.

```
 <?php
 $json_data='{
     "threads": 3,
     "posts": 0,
     "members": 2,
     "role_members": {
         "Guest": 0,
         "Unconfirmed": 0,
         "Moderator": 0,
         "Administrator": 0
             },
     "total_views": "16"
 }';
 $data = json_decode($json_data);
 ?>

 There are <?=$data->threads?> and <?=$data->role_members->guests?> 
 guests.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Replace with your json string
$json ='{"threads": 3,
"posts": 0,
"members": 2,
"role_members": {
    "Guest": 0,
    "Unconfirmed": 0,
    "Moderator": 0,
    "Administrator": 0
        },
"total_views": "16"}';

$arr = json_decode($json, true);

echo $arr['threads'];
```

Json_decode it. I usually make it an array with the second argument "true".

https://3v4l.org/cJFM0

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$json =<<<JSON
{
    "threads": 3,
    "posts": 0,
    "members": 2,
    "role_members": {
        "Guest": 0,
        "Unconfirmed": 0,
        "Moderator": 0,
        "Administrator": 0
            },
    "total_views": "16"
}
JSON;
$data = json_decode($json);
print $data->threads;
```

Output:

```
3
```